# Can ApplicationPoolIdentity be used to read/write files from/to a folder over network?

Tags: networking, security, iis, windows-server

There was a need to be able to read/write files from/to a network folder from the server with IIS.
Now I did not set it up at first so I don't know why - but a new user was created in the Application Pools to do that, and granted many privileges (even admin!).

But is it instead possible to make the default `ApplicationPoolIdentity` be able to read/write files over network?

From what I see a user was created on the server, named `user_to_read_write` and it is now used as the Identity as a Custom Account under Process Models in the Application Pools.

How can I change the current settings in a way that will still make the website be able to read/write from a certain folder over network but be more secure? I feel this is a really bad thing to have an administrator also run as an IIS identity

Do I need to leave that account but remove its admin privileges (And only leave it with read/write - to a specific folder even?), or I need to completely remove it, and there's a way to make `ApplicationPoolIdentity` be able to read/write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your IIS server is currently set up is somewhat correct
in that a custom account is used as the pool identity,
but the permissions are excessive.
You should not take the easy route of adding permissions until
your program works,
and it's a mistake to assign them to the
default identity so that all new pools will also have those
permissions.

You should read the Microsoft article
[Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).

Here are some quotes :

> **What about Application Pool Identities?**
>
> The good news is that application pool identities also use the machine
> account to access network resources. No changes are required.

For making this work then, all you need to do is on the computer
housing the share, is to right-click the Shared Folder,
select Properties > security > edit > add > object types >
Computers, and enter the computer name where your application is working from.

There is an excellent answer on the post
[IIS AppPoolIdentity and file system write access permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5439658/165358)
that summarizes the right way for such setup, if you prefer
avoiding default identities and permissions.

Below is quoted a part of this answer:

> In a shared environment where you possibly have several hundred sites,
> each with their own application pool and Application Pool Identity,
> you would store the site folders in a folder or volume that has had
> the `Users` group removed and the permissions set such that only
> Administrators and the SYSTEM account have access (with inheritance).
>
> You would then individually assign the requisite permissions each `IIS AppPool\[name]` requires on it's site root folder.
>
> You should also ensure that any folders you create where you store
> potentially sensitive files or data have the `Users` group removed.
> You should also make sure that any applications that you install don't
> store sensitive data in their `c:\program files\[app name]` folders
> and that they use the user profile folders instead.

References :

- [Application Pool Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)
- [Understanding identities in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/understanding-identities)
- [Permissions for Shared Folder for IIS 7 Application Pool Identity Across Domain](https://grekai.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/permissions-for-shared-folder-for-iis-7-application-pool-identity-across-domain/)

Comment: Thank you. I am working in an organization and I have no access to perform such tasks. But can you please tell me if I get it right so that I will know what to tell to the sysadmin: If the network folder I need access to (read/write) is `X:/files/`, then I first need to tell him to remove the admin privileges from `user_to_read_write`, then add it to that shared folder users? (the `Properties > security > edit > add > object types > Computers` part). And leave the application pools as it is now, i.e. with custom users?

Comment: Yes, that's right, and hopefully he will get it right the first time.